# Fixed header elements move on window reduced

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a fixed menu at the top of my screen, that works great, but when i got to make the browser window smaller, rather than all the elements in the menu staying where they are, they all dropdown underneath the menu to stay in the open window. My idea is that i want the positions to not become fixed when the window is made smaller, so they stay in position and can scroll to see the rest of the content. Is this possible?

Here is the code for the html of the menu header:

```
<div id="head_wrapper">
        <div id="head_company"></div><!---end head_company--->
        <div id="head_name"></div><!---end head_name---->

        <div id="head_search"></div><!---end head_search--->
        <div id="head_home" onclick="location.href='overview.php';"></div><!---end head_home--->
        <div id="head_settings" onclick="location.href='settings.php';"></div><!---end head_settings--->
        <div id="head_more"></div><!---end head_more--->


    </div><!---end head_wrapper--->
```

And here is the css for it:

```
#wrapper #head_wrapper {
    background-image: url(../images/general/head_bar.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    float: left;
    height: 44px;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto !important;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-left: 208px;
}
#wrapper #head_wrapper #head_company {
    background-image: url(../images/general/navs/arion_co_button.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 84px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#wrapper #head_wrapper #head_company:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/general/hover/company_hover.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 84px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#wrapper #head_wrapper #head_name {
    background-image: url(../images/general/navs/arion_logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 144px;
}
#wrapper #head_wrapper #head_more {
    background-image: url(../images/general/navs/head_more.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
#wrapper #head_wrapper #head_more:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/general/hover/head_more_hover.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#wrapper #head_wrapper #head_settings {
    background-image: url(../images/general/navs/head_settings.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 73px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#wrapper #head_wrapper #head_settings:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/general/hover/head_settings_hover.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 73px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#wrapper #head_wrapper #head_home {
    background-image: url(../images/general/navs/head_home.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 72px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#wrapper #head_wrapper #head_home:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/general/hover/head_home_hover.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 72px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#wrapper #head_wrapper #head_search {
    background-image: url(../images/general/navs/search_bar.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    width: 327px;
    margin-right:15px;
    background-position-y: 5px;
    margin-left:31%;
}
```

Thanks for any and all help

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `#wrapper` and `#head_wrapper` styles to:

```
width: 100%
min-width: 960px; /* set here a fixed value >= menu width */
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uPe2L/9/ (i've removed margins and backgrounds and added borders for clarity)

Btw, your code is wrong and messy. You should use a `ul` `li` structure.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, i tried your suggestions and it definately has helped, now when i make the windows smaller, nothing is fighting to stay int the window like it was before, except for the very last element the 'head_more' div, that for some reason does move to underneath the main menu, but that is only when the window is very small, too small to actually use, so i won't worry about that. BTW i usually do use a 'ul' 'li' structure, i have done it for all the other list style elements, however i don't know why i didn't do it this time, i will change that now, thanks again.